# Remove substring

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of data with the company names, but I get twice the names and some additional strings that I do not need:

[image]

I only want to remain the company names, for example:

[image]

How do I do this in excel?

Comment: Is your string **always** situated between `(#T)` and `(~US$)`?

Comment: The string that I want to extract is always before the first (~U$). Or alternatively, I think this refers to your question, the string of interest is always between the first "(#T) -" and second  "(~U$)".

Comment: If you really want to do this without formulas, just changing your actual input data, you can do this using text-to-columns. Just delimit by opening paranthesis and make sure to skip all but first column on import.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data is **always** like *company name (~US$) (#T) company name* you could do:

`=TRIM(LEFT(A1;FIND("(";A1)-1))`

It works like this:

[image]

*The string that I want to extract is always before the first (~U$).*

Then this will work for you.

Comment: @urdearboy How are you testing it?

Comment: Sorry I totally missed that the company name was twice. This works to pull out the **first** company name and my solution works to pull out the **second** company name ha. +1

Comment: @urdearboy No problem :)

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly for me. My question is answered.

Comment: Ah, I see, I didn't knew how to accept the solutions, but I found the check mark finally!

Answer (score 2):

To pull the string between the first instnace of `(#T)` and the second instance of `U$` try...

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("(#T)",A1)+7,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("U$)",A1,SEARCH("U$",A1))-1)
```

---

*This solution extracts the middle string and is result of me misreading the question, although it still does work*

Comment: This answer also works, thanks alot!